# Unit tests breaking using AngularJS, Pusher + Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, pusher

A project I am working is using `Pusher`, along with `Karma` for Unit tests. The unit tests are currently failing , citing the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Pusher
    at runBlock (/vagrant/front/src/app/index.run.js:9)
    at invoke (/vagrant/front/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4771)
    at /vagrant/front/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4578
    at forEach (/vagrant/front/bower_components/angular/angular.js:325)
    at createInjector (/vagrant/front/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4578)
    at WorkFn (/vagrant/front/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3120)
```

So I looked in `index.run.js` and found the issue:

```
    /** @ngInject */
  function runBlock($log,$rootScope) {

    $rootScope.wf = {
      api: '/api/v1',
      dateFormat: 'dd.MM.yyyy',
      dataRefreshListeners:{}
    };


    $rootScope.wf.pusher = new Pusher('3e2d8ab440fad96e67ff', {
       cluster: 'eu',
       encrypted: true
    });

  }
```

I thought it would be a simple case of defining `Pusher`, either in the function parameters, or stub it for the Unit tests.

I found the `pusher-test-stub` library, and added it that. This fixed all my previous errors but left me this one:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'PusherDefinition.Util')
  at /vagrant/front/bower_components/pusher-test-stub/dist/pusher-test-stub.js:155


[08:51:49] 'test' errored after 3.39 s
[08:51:49] Error: Failed 1 tests.
```

I did start messing around with the `pusher-test-stub.js` file, but figured the issue wasn't going to be with that library.

I also had a look in my `karma.conf.js` file, taking note of the directory paths. Changing these values didnt alter the failed unit test error message in either case (with `pusher-test-stub.js` and without).

Answer (score 0):

PhantomJS 1.9.8 is currently very old (2+ years) and is likely to break when working with modern web apps.

You should try 2.5 beta which features a recent Webkit engine: [PhantomJS downloads](https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads)

Comment: thanks for the reply, updated phantomjs in the package.json and ran npm install - no difference. I sohuld also add that the unit tests were working previously.

Comment: The version of npm phantomjs package is not the same as the version of phantomjs binary itself. What version is it now? `phantomjs --version`

Comment: Maybe PhantomJS version is not responsible for the error, but you're generally better off with a newer version of this software.

Comment: the project is running inside a vagrant box. running phantomjs --version tells me the program isn't installed. The version specified in the npm file is  "phantomjs": "~1.9.18",

Comment: 1.9.18 is the version of npm module "phantomjs", not the binary application "phantomjs" that it drives. I was talking about upgrading the latter. Judging by [module's page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs) the newer version that can drive PhantomJS v2.+ is called [phantomjs-prebuilt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs-prebuilt)